# Java Array exercise

Tags: java, arrays

I have this array exercise. I want to understand how things work, if someone can

1. we have the object array of type int called `index` with 4 elements
2. we have  the object array of type String called `islands` with 4 elements

I don't understand how things are passing to each other, I need a good explanation.

```
class Dog {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    int [] index = new int[4];
    index[0] = 1;
    index[1] = 3;
    index[2] = 0;
    index[3] = 2;
    String [] islands = new String[4];

    islands[0] = "Bermuda";
    islands[1] = "Fiji";
    islands[2] = "Azores";
    islands[3] = "Cozumel";

    int y = 0;
    int ref;

    while (y < 4) {
      ref = index[y];
      System.out.print("island = ");
      System.out.println(islands[ref]);
      y ++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is your "Specific" question?

Comment: Consider using a for loop like for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) instead of your while loop. Just a better style. Anyway what is your question!

Comment: Also note that "homework" tag has been officially deprecated

Comment: You would need to specify your question a bit better in order to get very good and accurate answer. Otherwise we could write half of a book explaining fundamentals of Java

Answer (score 6):

Take a pen and paper and make a table like this, and go through the iterations:

```
 y    ref    islands[ret]
---   ---    ------------
 0     1      Fiji
 1     3      Cozumel
 2     0      Bermuda
 3     2      Azores
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've added `index` in the array named index then accessing the same value in while loop

```
int y=0;
ref = index[y]; // now ref = 1
islands[ref] // means islands[1] which returns the value `Fiji` that is stored in 1st position
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you make an array that holds `int`s, the array has length 4 (4 variables can be in it):

```
int [] intArray = new int[4];
```

Your array is called index which may be confusing for the explanation. The **index** of an array is which "position" you are referring to and is between `0` and the `length-1` (inclusive). You can use it in two ways:

```
int myInt = intArray[0]; //get whatever is at index 0 and store it in myInt
intArray[0] = 4; //store the number 4 at index 0
```

The following code does nothing more than get a number from the first array and use it to access a variable in the second array.

```
ref = index[y];
System.out.println(islands[ref])
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it understand, take a paper and pen and jot down the arrays in table form and iterate through the loop to understand. (back in school days, our teacher(s) called it a dry run)

First we represent the data

```
Iteration    y           ref ( `ref = index[y]`)  islands
  1          0                 1                    Fiji 
  2          1                 3                   Cozumel
  3          2                 0                   Bermuda
  4          3                 2                    Azores
```

So you can go through the iterations 
**Iteration 1**

```
y=0
ref = index[y], i.e. index[0] i.e 1
System.out.print("island = "); prints island = 
System.out.println(islands[ref]); islands[ref] i.e islands[1] i.e Fiji
```

hence for *iteration 1* output will be

```
island = Fiji
```